# How to set scroll for div in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, scroll

I am displaying multiple name within one div and then that div  should be scrollable.

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
   {{#linkTo "names"}}Display Names{{/linkTo}}
   {{outlet}}
 </script>
```

when i click on display name i have to display all name so i have created another one template like this

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="names">
    <div class="container">
     {{#each model}}
       <div>{{name}}</div>
     {{/each}}
    </div>
  </script>
```

I have to apply scroll for container div if children of that div height is more than that div.

I have done in ember.js file like this

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('names');
});

App.NamesRoute=Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return namedetails;
  }
});
```

It is displaying but i don't know how to set scroll for that container div in ember.js

how to set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically all you need to do is to apply `overflow: auto;` to your `container` class:

#### CSS

```
.container {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

But if you want the css to be applied to your `names` template corresponding `div` then you should add a `view` for your `names` template and define the appropriate `classNameBindings`:

#### CSS

```
.auto-scroll {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

#### Javascript

```
App.NamesView = Ember.View.extend({
  classNameBindings: ['auto-scroll']
});
```

Note that the `overflow:auto` shows scrollbars when the `div` holding the content is not sufficient in size. Also worth mentioning is that the `overflow` can be set to behave differently, e.g.:

```
overflow: auto; /* scroll bars appear, only when they are needed */
overflow: scroll; /* scroll bars appear always */

overflow-x: auto; /* only horizontal scroll bars appear, when they are needed */
overflow-y: auto; /* only vertical scroll bars appear, when they are needed */

overflow-x: scroll; /* horizontal scroll bars appear always */
overflow-y: scroll; /* vertical scroll bars appear always */
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: how to make mvc structure in ember.js. in the sense i want separate the file in ember.js ...can tell me?

Comment: @silvesterprabu, this seams like a different question to me, did my answer solve the problem of this question?

Comment: no...but i know this is correct way  before asking you....i have tried but i am not get correct out put